# Watson Assistant - Condition with variable

Tags: watson-assistant

Can I use a condition with a variable that I created? Specifically, how can I indicate that the variable value [text and/or numbers ] with max of 15 characters for the user input? I've been trying to set the condition in order to verify the user input of characters, with max of 15 characters between text and/or numbers, but it dosen't work. I've made a variable [ $codice_fiscale ] but I can't aplly the condition. Can you please help me in order to make it work?

Comment: Please add more details. You can reference / use a context variable in conditions.

Comment: The user's response must contain only 15 characters between letters and numbers. This input is collected by the $ code_fiscale variable.
How can I make the condition that checks the number of characters?

Comment: Take a look at the regex functionality

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I don't understand how I can do it :-(

Comment: Try it out a couple times and add your code to the question.